# Parse Queries through Nested For Loops is Giving Duplication of Results

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to loop through an array to query my order class to find an associated id, then loop through
another class with that id.

There are 4 elements in the origin array, and they should match to an id each of which have 43 elements in the 3rd query.

However instead of getting 43 results from the 3rd query per id, I'm getting 12*43 results.

I can't figure out how my code is wrong and I've tried containedIn also without any results.

```
    $scope.positionIds = [];
    $scope.dataDictionary = {};
    $scope.quotes = function () {
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.positions.length; i++){
    var positionNow  = $scope.positions[i];
    var orderQuery = new Parse.Query('Order');
    orderQuery.equalTo('objectId', positionNow );
    orderQuery.find({
          success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
              for (var j=0; j < result.length; j++){
                      $scope.positionIds.push(result[j].attributes.positionId);
              }
              for (var k=0; k < $scope.positionIds.length; k++){
                    var portfolioQuery = new Parse.Query('DayPosition');
                    portfolioQuery.limit(1000);
                    var positionSecond = $scope.positionIds[k];
                    portfolioQuery.equalTo('positionId', positionSecond);
                    console.log("positionId", $scope.positionIds[k]);
                    portfolioQuery.find({
                          success: function(result) {
                            console.log("count", result.length);
                              for (var h=0; h < result.length; h++){
                                    // console.log("count", result.length);
                                    console.log("double inside data time", result[h].createdAt);
                                    console.log("double inside data id", $scope.positionIds[k]);
                                    console.log("value", result[h].attributes.currentValue);
                                    var values = [];
                                    values.push([result[h].createdAt,
                                    result[h].attributes.currentValue]);
                                    if (!$scope.dataDictionary[result[h].attributes.positionId]){
                                        $scope.dataDictionary[result[h].attributes.positionId] = [];
                                    } else {
                                      $scope.dataDictionary[result[h].attributes.positionId].push(values); 
                                    }
                              }
                              console.log("final data", $scope.dataDictionary);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                      console.log("this error", error);
                    }
                }); 
            }      
          },
          error: function (error) {
            console.log("this error", error);
          }
      }); 
  }
};
```

Comment: To begin with, you have two `result` attributes working on different nested scopes. That's not a good idea.

Comment: I fixed it, the answer was to move the loops into the success callback of my other Parse Query. Creation of a scope array that was then looped through was multiplying the number of loops by itself.